# Creating sequence of dates in R by group, dependent on another variable

Tags: r

Right now, my dataset is in wide format, meaning I have one row per person, but I want a long dataset, with multiple rows per person. I have two date variables, ADATE and DDATE, that I want to use as my start and end points, respectively. For example, if someone's ADATE is 02/04/10 and DDATE is 02/07/10, I want 4 rows:

Have:

```
ID ADATE     DDATE     
1  02/04/10  02/07/10
```

Want:

```
ID ADATE     DDATE     NEW_DATE
1  02/04/10  02/07/10  02/04/10
1  02/04/10  02/07/10  02/05/10
1  02/04/10  02/07/10  02/06/10
1  02/04/10  02/07/10  02/07/10
```

I have multiple datasets that I want to do this for, and I have written code that works for every single dataset except one...I'm not sure why. This is my attempt and the error I get:

```
jan15_long <- chf_jan15 %>%
  mutate(NEW_DATE = as.Date(ADATE)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  complete(NEW_DATE = seq.Date(as.Date(ADATE), as.Date(DDATE), by = "day")) %>%
  fill(vars) %>%
  ungroup()
Error in seq.Date(as.Date(ADATE), as.Date(DDATE), by = "day") : 
  'from' must be of length 1
```

The above code gives me what I want and runs perfectly for every other dataset I have (10 out of 11).

Is there a better way to do this? `dplyr` makes the most sense to me, so hopefully there's a solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are more than one row, the `seq` needs to be looped.  We can use `map2`.  Also, based on the `format` of the 'DATE' columns, the `as.Date` needs a `format` argument i.e. `as.Date(ADATE, "%m/%d/%y")` (assuming it is month/day/year format)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
chf_jan15 %>%
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with("DATE")), mdy) %>%
    mutate(random_date = map2(ADATE, DDATE, seq, by = "day")) %>%
    unnest(c(random_date))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#     ID ADATE      DDATE      random_date
#  <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     
#1     1 2010-02-04 2010-02-07 2010-02-04 
#2     1 2010-02-04 2010-02-07 2010-02-05 
#3     1 2010-02-04 2010-02-07 2010-02-06 
#4     1 2010-02-04 2010-02-07 2010-02-07
```

---

If there is only a single row, after converting to `Date` class, the `complete` should work

```
library(tidyr)
chf_jan15 %>%
   mutate_at(vars(ends_with("DATE")), as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%y") %>%
   mutate(NEW_DATE = ADATE) %>%      
   complete(NEW_DATE = seq(ADATE, DDATE, by = 'day')) %>%
   fill(c(ID, ADATE, DDATE))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  NEW_DATE      ID ADATE      DDATE     
#  <date>     <int> <date>     <date>    
#1 2010-02-04     1 2010-02-04 2010-02-07
#2 2010-02-05     1 2010-02-04 2010-02-07
#3 2010-02-06     1 2010-02-04 2010-02-07
#4 2010-02-07     1 2010-02-04 2010-02-07
```

If there is a single row for each each 'ID', then we can `group_split` and use `complete`

```
chf_jan15 %>%
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with("DATE")), as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%y") %>%
    mutate(NEW_DATE = ADATE) %>%
    group_split(ID) %>%
    map_dfr(~ .x %>%
                 complete(NEW_DATE = seq(ADATE, DDATE, by = 'day')) %>%
                  fill(c(ID, ADATE, DDATE)))
```

#### data

```
chf_jan15 <- structure(list(ID = 1L, ADATE = "02/04/10", 
    DDATE = "02/07/10"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: Hi akrun. I have to do this within each group. Should I add a `group_by` before `mutate_at`? Thanks!

Comment: @user122514  It is not needed because the `map2` is loopiing over each row

Comment: Hi akrun. The first chunk of code works, but the second one doesn't. I'm still getting an error saying that  'from' must be of length 1.

Comment: @user122514  sorry, it needs a `group_by` before `complete` updated the code.  Please check

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wish I could figure out why exactly the `seq` function is giving me an error in my code and in your second chunk, but it'll remain a mystery for now...

Comment: @user122514  Let me add one more ID and see if it shows an error

Comment: @user122514 The `complete` won't work here if there is more than one row as the `seq` is not vectorized

Comment: The odd thing, though, is that it works for every other dataset I've tried (they all have the same structure and same variables). I wish I could share the dataset with you, but it's ok. Maybe I'll investigate again in the future.

Comment: @user122514  It is because of the `seq` which takes the from, to of length 1

Comment: Thanks! I will try to read up on `map2` as I don't really use the `purrr` package.